# Combine PDO::FETCH_OBJ with PDO:FETCH_GROUP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

### Code 1

```php
<?php
function allTypes()
{
  $stmt = option('db')->prepare("
    SELECT
      slug, id, title
    FROM types
  ");
  $stmt->execute();
  return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}

print_r(allTypes());
```

### Results code 1

I can use an object call to get the values. However, the keys are numbers like `$results[0]->title`.

I would like them to be slug, like `$results['motionsspar']->title`.

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [slug] => motionsspar
            [id] => 1
            [title] => Motionsspår
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [slug] => utegym
            [id] => 2
            [title] => Utegym
        )

)
```

### Code 2

```php
<?php
function allTypes()
{
  $stmt = option('db')->prepare("
    SELECT
      slug, id, title
    FROM types
  ");
  $stmt->execute();
  return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ | PDO::FETCH_GROUP);
}

print_r(allTypes());
```

### Results code 2

I can now use keys like `$results['motionsspar'][0]->title`. However, there is no need to have it nested inside `[0]`.

A perfect call would be `$results['motionsspar']->title`.

```
Array
(
    [motionsspar] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [title] => Motionsspår
                )

        )

    [utegym] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [title] => Utegym
                )

        )

)
```

I would like the best from both worlds here. Is it possible or do I need to foreach it as an own loop? (I use PHP)

Comment: It might work with `PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE`. [Here's a good site about different fetch modes with examples and combinations](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/fetch_modes#FETCH_UNIQUE). Check the second example for FETCH_UNIQUE. Try that in combination with FETCH_OBJ

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Yes, thanks! This works `$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ | PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE);`

Comment: Write an answer where you show how you solved it. Can definitely be useful for future visitors.

Comment: It's closed because of duplicated question. However my question is not the same as the suggested one. Well, you helpt me anyway. Thanks!

Comment: How it's not the same? Where the "PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE is giving you an array indexed by the field listed in SELECT clause first" is different from the suggestion given you in the comment?